# 5.6 Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following theorem:

> **Theorem 5.6** Equivalent conditions to be an eigenvalue:
>   Suppose V is finite-dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V),$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}.$ Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T ;
>
> (b) $T-\lambda I$ is not injective;
>
> (c) $T- \lambda I$ is not surjective;
>
> (d)$T- \lambda I$ is not invertible

Proof: Conditions (a) and (b) are equivalent because the equation $Tv = \lambda v$ is equivalent to the equation $(T - \lambda I)v = 0$.

From here I understand that $v \neq 0$, so that $(T - \lambda I)$ is a linear transformation that sends v to $Tv - \lambda v$. But from here I don't see why this implies that $(T - \lambda I)v = 0$ is not injective.

Can someone please explain? Thank you!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Could you explain what is the intuitive meaning of $(T -\lambda I)$ in here? And what is the meaning of nontrivial kernel?

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ So, this is an example of $A$ and $v$ such $Av = 0$ but neither $v$ nor $A$ are zero. The set of all $v$ such that $Av = 0$ is called as the kernel of $A$. If $v = 0$ is the only vector in the kernel then it is called trivial, otherwise it is called non-trivial.

Comment: If you are looking for vectors that map to multiples of themselves, you are looking for vectors that map to zero under $T-\lambda I$. “Nontrivial kernel” just means “there are vectors, other than the zero vector, that map to zero”. And finally, recall that for an operator on a finite dimensional vector space, injective, surjective, and invertible are all equivalent.

Comment: I don’t understand your question; you chopped up my statement mid-sentence, so that it doesn’t even make sense anymore. You do understand that sentences need to be read in full?

Comment: If your vector space is one-dimensional, then every linear transformation is of the form $\mathbf{v}\mapsto \lambda\mathbf{v}$ for some fixed $\lambda$, and every nonzero vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$; the linear transformations here *are* exactly those of the form $\lambda I$. So what? What are you trying to say, what are you trying to ask? Complete sentences, please.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you, I got it now!

Comment: @MorganRodgers I do understand what does it mean, but the class that I'm taking and the book doesn't use the term "nontrivial kernel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The false statement

If $(T-\lambda I) v = 0$, then it **no way means** that $T - \lambda I = 0$.  Counterexample: suppose $T$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb F^2$ whose matrix w.r.t. some basis $e_1,e_2$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
then for $\lambda = 1$ and $v = [1, 0]^{\mathsf T}$, you could verify that 
$$
(T-I)v = 0, 
$$
but clearly $T - I \neq 0$ in this case, and $v \neq 0$, either.

#### Preparations

By definition, $T \in \mathcal L (V, W)$ is injective $\iff$

- whenever $v,w \in V$ satisfy $Tv = Tw$, $v = w$.

Equivalently, i.e. take the contrapositive statement,

- whenever $v,w \in V$ that $v \neq w$,  $Tv \neq Tw$.

Therefore, $T$ is not injective $\iff$

- there exists $v, w \in V$ that $v \neq w$ but $T v = Tw$.

Since $T$ is a linear mapping, $Tv = Tw \iff T(v - w) = 0$. Let $u = v -w$, then we actually have

- $T$ is not injective $\iff$ there exists $u \neq 0$ that $Tu = 0$ $\iff$ $\mathrm{null}\,T \neq \{0\}(\bigstar)$.

#### Solve the problem

Now get back to the question. By definition,

- (a) holds $\iff$ there exists $ v \neq 0$ that $T v = \lambda v$,

equivalently, $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$. As a linear mapping, by applying $(\bigstar)$ to $T-\lambda I$, we get that equivalently $T -\lambda I$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2):

In order to tackle your question, we need the following theorems:

**1-** A linear map $A$ is injective, iff it has a trivial kernel. (That is, Ker($A$)={0})

**2-** Let $V,W$ be vector spaces, such that dim$V$ = dim$W$, $\varphi:V\rightarrow W$ a linear map. Then, the following statements are equivalent:

*a.* $\varphi$ is injective;

*b.*  $\varphi$ is surjective;

*c.*  $\varphi$ is bijective.

**3-** A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is bijective, iff $f$ is invertible.

Do you see how the rest of your theorem follows?
(Hint: $T-\lambda L$ is a linear transformation)

Answer (score -1):

Not injective means that $\text{null}\ (T-\lambda I) \neq \{0\}$ (see 3.16). Thus $(T-\lambda I)$ is not injective if and only if there exists some $v \in \text{null}\ (T-\lambda I), v \neq 0$, so if and only if for some $v \neq 0$, $(T-\lambda I)v = 0$.

Comment: $(T-\lambda I)v$ is a vector, not a linear transformation, so it cannot be injective (or not injective, for that matter).

Comment: This just looks like a typo to me...

Comment: @IAmNoOne yeah it was a typo. Why the downvotes...